# What is the best way to send HTTP requests from Windows Powershell?

Tags: http, networking, powershell

What is the best way to send HTTP requests from Windows Powershell?

Comment: The best way really depends on what task you are trying to accomplish as the two answers below have noted.  WebClient is the simplest, but HttpWebRequest is the most flexible.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Found one way:

```
$page = (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://localhost/")
```

Thanks to Steven Murawski for his comment:

> The best way really depends on what
>   task you are trying to accomplish as
>   the two answers below have noted.
>   **WebClient** is the simplest, but
>   **HttpWebRequest** is the most flexible.

Comment: If you need to control anything related to timeouts then you must use httpwebrequest or webrequest.

Answer (score 12):

In PowerShell 3.0+ you can use [Invoke-WebRequest](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx)

```
$page = Invoke-WebRequest "http://localhost/"
```

Answer (score 2):

System.Net.WebClient is the easiest way to do it for simple GET request. However if you need to do a POST request for a form then you will need to use System.Net.HttpWebRequest.