# How to make an authenticated web request in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

In C#, I might do something like this:

```
System.Net.WebClient w = new System.Net.WebClient();
w.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, auth, domain);
string webpage = w.DownloadString(url);
```

Is there a Powershell version of this, or should I just call through to the [CLR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340553/what-is-the-best-way-to-send-http-requests-from-windows-powershell)?

Comment: In my enterprise, some guy dolike to annoy other with "usefull" preferences in IE.  Is it possible to make http request without using IE?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The PowerShell is almost exactly the same.

```
$webclient = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.Credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username, $password, $domain)
$webpage = $webclient.DownloadString($url)
```

Comment: did this stop working for anyone else, all of the sudden? (401) Unauthorized

Comment: @meffect The comment below helped me. 

     `$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $password)`

Comment: Note that if you just want to use the current logon credentials (e.g. to access an authenticated server on the intranet), you can use `$webclient.UseDefaultCredentials=$true` (as in [Ralph's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12421075/1443496)).

Answer (score 30):

For those that need Powershell to return additional information like the Http StatusCode, here's an example. Included are the two most likely ways to pass in credentials.

Its a slightly modified version of this SO answer:
[How to obtain numeric HTTP status codes in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473358/how-to-obtain-numeric-http-status-codes-in-powershell)

```
$req = [system.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
# method 1 $req.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
# method 2 $req.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username, $pwd, $domain); 
try
{
    $res = $req.GetResponse()
}
catch [System.Net.WebException]
{
    $res = $_.Exception.Response
}

$int = [int]$res.StatusCode
$status = $res.StatusCode
return "$int $status"
```

Comment: Excellent additional answer, this was actually exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I had to replace `new NetworkCredential` with `$passwd = ConvertTo-SecureString "nowisthetime4U" -AsPlainText -Force;` followed by `$request.Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("pwatson_at_phs_org", $passwd);`

Comment: New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential instead of new NetworkCredential

Answer (score 2):

In some case NTLM authentication still won't work if given the correct credential.

There's a mechanism which will void NTLM auth within WebClient, see here for more information: [System.Net.WebClient doesn't work with Windows Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030177/system-net-webclient-doesnt-work-with-windows-authentication)

If you're trying above answer and it's still not working, follow the above link to add registry to make the domain whitelisted.

Post this here to save other's time ;)