# How to login to website with basic authentication using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use PowerShell to log into a website and download a file.

However I can't get PS to pass the credentials properly.

Here is my PS:

```
$webclient = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.Credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential("username","password","domain")
$webpage = $webclient.DownloadString("url goes here")
```

Here is the log in box I get when I hit the site in IE:
[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is what I got to work.  I believe the key part is the "Basic" in the CredentialCache

```
$webclient = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$credCache = new-object System.Net.CredentialCache
$creds = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential("un","pw")
$credCache.Add("url", "Basic", $creds)
$webclient.Credentials = $credCache
$webpage = $webclient.DownloadString("url")
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to use `Invoke-WebRequest` instead of the `WebClient`:

```
$securepassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("username", $securepassword)
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "url goes here" -Credential $credentials
```

I based the code on [this blog article by Douglas Tarr](http://douglastarr.com/using-powershell-3-invoke-restmethod-with-basic-authentication-and-json).  Note that in the article the username and password are confused, but I've fixed them in my sample.

Answer (score 5):

For some reason I wasn't able to get any of these solutions to work (using PowerShell 5 on Win 10). Could perhaps be an obvious, fool-hardy situation since I don't use PS very often. But FWIW this is how I was able to get it to work, by manually setting the Authorization header.

```
$url = "{url here}"
$username = "{username here}"
$password = "{password here}"

$b = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($username + ":" + $password)
$p = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($b)

$creds = "Basic " + $p

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Headers @{"Authorization"=$creds}
```

For whatever reason, the other answers here did make requests but no Authorization header was ever sent.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me trying to fetch a file out of my Artifactory instance. Props.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it,

first created a **download.ps1** file that contains the powershell script,

Then running this script through a batch file:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -File  C:\Users\SS\Desktop\download.ps1
```

**this is the PowerShell script:**

```
    $Username = 'Domain\user'
    $Password = 'pass'
    $Url = "http://google.com/target/filename.zip"
    $Path = "C:\path\to\downloaded\file\filename.zip"
    $WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
    $WebClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.Networkcredential($Username, $Password)
    $WebClient.DownloadFile( $url, $path )
```

Answer (score -1):

What you have should work (try the code with some other sites).  Normally, an invalid username/password would cause the code to fail with a 401 error (not the windows security login window).  The problem may be related to the web site requiring [Windows Integrated Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030177/system-net-webclient-doesnt-work-with-windows-authentication)