# How do I pass user/password to navigate method in a InternetExplorer.Application object

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, powershell, vbscript

I want to automate a thing in IE using power shell , I have the following snippet:

```
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application";
$ie.navigate('http://urlWithAuthentication.com');
```

this url has http authentication, so the browser prompts for the user and password, the previous script works fine, but I would like to not interactively set the user and password.

for example:

**This does not exist, looking for something similar**

```
$ie.navigate('http://urlWithAuthentication.com','user','password');
```

there's nothing about authentication in the method documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752093%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I've found questions similar but they were targeting when there's a login page (i.e. user/pass form), in this case I'm targeting to handle the browser's builtin user/pass promt.

Comment: See here for a potential solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12282842/how-to-login-to-website-with-basic-authentication-using-powershell

Comment: @DavidBrabant that's not the solution I'm looking for, cause System.Net.WebClient just donwloads the resource, I would need to parse the html  and manipulate dom and then build another request to interact with the page. all those things are encapsulated in InternetExplorer.Application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is a function within the COM Object because i've also looked for this in the past, my own automation scripts use `Wscript.Shell` to send the Username, press tab, sent the password and then send the enter key.

```
# setup ie object and open website
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application";
$ie.navigate('http://urlWithAuthentication.com');
$passwordSent = 0
# wait for website to load
While ($ie.ReadyState -ne 4)
{
    Sleep -Milliseconds 500
        if ($ie.ReadyState -eq 1) {
             if ($passwordSent -eq 0) {
             $comShell = New-Object -com "Wscript.Shell" 
             $comShell.sendkeys($password)
             $comShell.sendkeys("{ENTER}")
             $passwordSent = 1;
        }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I also did not find any other approach,  you almost wrote the right script,  except that the part of sending the keys goes inside the while loop, the user/password prompt happens when ReadyState is "Loaded"

Answer (score -1):

This is what worked for me. It works, however I receive an error because of the password I used. I think I need to make a new function to pass the password to the login mask,

```
# setup ie object and open website
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application";
$ie.navigate('http://YOURWEBSITE');
$passwordSent = 0
# wait for website to load
While ($ie.ReadyState -ne 4)
{
 Sleep -Milliseconds 500
  $comShell = New-Object -com "Wscript.Shell" 
  $comShell.sendkeys($username)
  $comShell.sendkeys("{TAB}")
  $comShell.sendkeys($password)
  $comShell.sendkeys("{ENTER}")
  $passwordSent = 1;
}
```