# I am not able to do create database in CouchDB 3.x with Admin

Tags: powershell, couchdb, couchdb-2.x

Just installed couchdb 3.00 version in windows machine and configured as single node.

Defined admin in installation, even after installation. Restarted couchDB after definitions.

My admins appears in UI:
[image]

But when i try to create db via shell script it responses:

[image]

I am absolutely sure that my passwords are correct.

I wonder if there is a bug or mistake i've made.

Comment: If you try to create a database with the same user through Fauxton, does that work?

Comment: @AlexisCôté yes it does.

Comment: What if you use -Method POST

Comment: I'm not a WIndows user, but I don't see any credentials included in that CLI command, unless they are automatically picked up from somewhere?

Comment: @DominicBarnes they are part of the dsn

Comment: @AlexisCôté still same..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not related to CouchDB, rather the allowed authentication methods with Invoke-WebRequest.

Though I cannot find any documentation that explicitly states URL credentials *are not* supported, I do find in the PowerShell documentation<sup>1</sup> a list of authentication methods that *are* supported:

> **-Authentication**
>
> Specifies the explicit authentication type to use for the request. The default is None. Authentication cannot be used with
>   UseDefaultCredentials.
>
> Available Authentication Options:
>
> **None**: This is the default option when Authentication isn't supplied;
>   no explicit authentication is used.
>
> **Basic**: Requires Credential. The credentials are sent in an RFC 7617 Basic Authentication header in the format of
>   base64(user:password).
>
> **Bearer**: Requires Token. Sends an RFC
>   6750 Authorization: Bearer header with the supplied token. This is an
>   alias for OAuth
>
> **OAuth**: Requires Token. Sends an RFC 6750
>   Authorization: Bearer header with the supplied token. This is an alias
>   for Bearer

I interpret the above to mean the authentication method you are using ***is not supported.***

Here's one example using Basic authentication, one of surely hundreds of ways to perform your task.

```
 # setup variables to form a HTTP Basic Authorization
 $uid = "<username>"
 $pwd = "<password>"
 # Convert the Basic credentials to bytes
 $atob = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($uid +":" + $pwd)
 # To Base64 encoding
 $auth = "Basic " + [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($atob)
 # Create the database
 Invoke-WebRequest -Method PUT -Url http://127.0.0.1:5964/abc -Headers @{"Authorization"=$auth}
```

FWIW, cURL allows the ease of inline URL http authentication, but that may not be an option.

The above code borrows from this [SO Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12282842/how-to-login-to-website-with-basic-authentication-using-powershell) answer regarding Basic authentication.

<sup>1</sup> [PowerShell Documentation Version 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7)

Comment: it worked !  I used to use powershell for modifying couchdb when the version was 2.3.1.
As it pointed out [here](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/intro/api.html)  , i used url credential in powershell but seems like there is a difference in handling requests between cURL and powershell's invoke-WebRequest method

Answer (score 1):

At starting by Couchdb 3 is mandatory using autenthication for PUT or DELETE operation.
Invoke-WebRequest had -Authorization param for this purpose.
But authentication is in clear format. I use PSCouchDB (https://pscouchdb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auth.html) for used authentication in SecureString password object.

For example:

```
$password = "password" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

Set-CouchDBSession -UserId admin -Password $password

Set-CouchDBSession -UserId admin    # prompt password

New-CouchDBDatabase -Database test
```