# NTLM over HTTP: Any C# client implementation?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, windows-authentication, ntlm

I need to programmatically download a file from a [SharePoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SharePoint) server.

When I download the file with [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/) it looks like a single request, but [Httpfox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/httpfox/) shows that the HTTPS conversation is actually 4 requests:

```
REQ1: GET https://mycorp.raxsp.com/_windows/default.aspx?ReturnUrl=/personal/mycorp_user1/_vti_bin/cmis/rest?getRepositories
RESP1: 401 Unauthorized, WWW-Authenticate NTLM

REQ2: Authorization NTLM TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAB4IIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=
RESP2: 401, WWW-Authenticate    NTLM TlRMTVNTUAACAAAACgAKADgAAAAFgokC+[...]

REQ3: Authorization NTLM TlRMTVNTUAADAAAAGAAYAIAAAAAYA[...]
RESP3: 302 Found, Set-Cookie FedAuth=77u/PD94bW[...], Location /personal/mycorp_user1/_vti_bin/cmis/rest?getRepositories

REQ4: GET /personal/mycorp_user1/_vti_bin/cmis/rest?getRepositories
RESP4: 200 OK, <download begins>
```

I tried downloading the file with a simple [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) with user/password, but as expected I just get the error 401. I am considering implementing the whole 4 requests, computing challenges with the [NTLM over HTTP authentication algorithm](http://www.innovation.ch/personal/ronald/ntlm.html) ([spec](http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/e/6/ae6e4142-aa58-45c6-8dcf-a657e5900cd3/%5BMS-NTHT%5D.pdf)), but that sounds very error-prone...

Is there a client-side library or a code snippet that does NTLM over HTTP authentication?
It is for [an Open Source project](http://cmissync.com), so must be Open Source, and preferably using [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx).
No Kerberos/SSO/domains involved.

Comment: possible duplicate of [System.Net.WebClient doesn't work with Windows Authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030177/system-net-webclient-doesnt-work-with-windows-authentication)

Comment: @gilly3: It is a different problem: 1) I have no problem with IE8 2) That question's username "boxname\peter" indicates domains are involved. My usernames contains no \ . 3) Question says "Both client and IIS are on the same Windows", which is not my case. 4) Accepted solution says "type the host name for the sites that are on the local computer". I have **no** sites on the local computer. That problem happens when both client and server are on the same machine, which is not my case.

Comment: As I see from requests, they are as following: Authenticate, Set-Cookie, Redirect, Download document having cooke set. When you use just HttpWebRequest, it may authenticate your request but won't ask for document with client cookie sent with authentication. So I assume NTLM is ok here, while the rest is not working

Answer (score 1):

We download files from SharePoint all the time with this code using `System.Net.WebClient`

```
public static byte [] downloadSharepointFile (string url){
      using (var client = new WebClient { Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain") })
          {
               client.Headers.Add("Accept: application/json");
               return client.DownloadData(url);
          }
}
```

Comment: it works on mine. if it doesn't for you let me know and we can compare project settings