# powershell WebClient downloadFile always returns 401 though NetworkCredential passed correctly

Tags: powershell, webclient

I am trying to download jenkins.war file through powershell on windows server, but I get 401 Unauthorized error in downloadFile. I passed correct network credentials still getting this error. Below is my code:

```
$source = "http://mirrors.jenkins.io/war-stable/latest/jenkins.war"
$destination = "$jenkinsDir\jenkins.war"
$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient

$credCache = new-object System.Net.CredentialCache
$creds = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential("admin", "P@ssw0rd")
$credCache.Add("http://mirrors.jenkins.io/war-stable/latest/jenkins.war", "Basic", $creds)
$client.Credentials = $credCache

$client.downloadFile($source, $destination)
```

How to get rid of this 401 error?

I also tried this link [System.Net.WebClient doesn't work with Windows Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030177/system-net-webclient-doesnt-work-with-windows-authentication) but no luck.

Comment: I previously used the below script to download files - does this work for you?
In my experience proxies and passing credentials can be a fickle thing...

$UserPath = "$($env:USERPROFILE)"
$site = 'https://www.sqlite.org/download.html'
$proxy = [System.Net.WebRequest]::GetSystemWebProxy().GetProxy($site)
Invoke-webrequest -Uri $site -Proxy $proxy -ProxyUseDefaultCredentials -TimeOutSec 10 -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue -OutFile $UserPath\Desktop\download.html

If that works it should just be a matter of changing $site and $outfile

Comment: Why are you using `WebClient`?  Look at `Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile`

Comment: @Shovers_ Got same error: Invoke-webrequest : Proxy Authorization Required
Description: Authorization is required for access to this proxy
Error Code: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT; Windows NT 10.0; en-US) WindowsPowerShell/5.1.15063.1387 Error Detail: Logon failure Invoke-webrequest -Uri $site -Proxy $proxy -ProxyUseDefaultCredential ... + CategoryInfo   : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException + FullyQualifiedErrorId: WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

Comment: I'd have to guess then that the account your using either doesn't have access to get out to that site, or some other thing in between is blocking it, either a firewall or some other security product. If you do "runas" on Iexplore.ex (or your browser) and use those credentials do you get out to the site or 407 ?

Comment: @Shovers_ If I open above url in chrome/IE, it asks me to Sign-in to proxy url, after entering same credentials, the download of file starts, so its working with same credentials in browser but not with powershell. Also If I click on Remember me in IE then above powershell script runs successfully by adding client.UseDefaultCredentials = $true  but I cannot do this for all other environments.

Comment: the only other thing I can think of is instead of UseDefaultCredentials is to prompr for them using Get-Credential


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6