# How to download an image file from a website using PowerShell or from Windows command line?

Tags: powershell, cmd

I'm trying to download an image from the internet using a command prompt like PowerShell or the Windows command line.

I tried running this line that I found online:

```
wget http://imgur.com/ -OutFile out.jpg
```

That's an example, not the actual parameters that I used.

I ran this in PowerShell, but I get

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException

I'm not very experienced in the command line and don't know what to do from here.

Comment: Have you considered this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22447326/powershell-download-image-from-an-image-url

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell - Download Image from an image url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22447326/powershell-download-image-from-an-image-url)

Comment: `http://imgur.com/` is clearly not the url of an image. Is that really the url you used?

Comment: While you've included _some_ code it's not the actual code you're using, you've also only included part of the error message - both of these hinder any meaningful answer to your question. I'd recommend reading [ask] and the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) as at the moment your question is missing the basics that are expected when asking a question. It's likely to be downvoted and closed until you include these basics.

Comment: wget is in this case an alias for invoke-webrequest, which won't run in a cmd.exe shell...

Comment: @PeterSchneider - Perhaps aliases are more trouble than benefit.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Invoke-WebRequest`:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://i.imgur.com/XoSe08F.jpg -OutFile test.jpg -UseBasicParsing
```

In case of Edge or Internet Explorer is not installed use the `-UseBasicParsing` switch, otherwise `Invoke-WebRequest` might [fail](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3042).

Answer (score 1):

- for windows 10 in cmd prompt
- curl https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuGD9.jpg -o outputfile.jpg