# Site certificate fails when I enable https decryption in Fiddler 4

Tags: powershell, authentication, https, fiddler

I have a PowerShell script that uploads a batch of files to lingq.com.
I created it the following way: I logged in to the site via browser, and made an upload manually through the web page. I grabbed the request in Fiddler, then duplicated it in PowerShell, including the authentication cookies. I'd just swap out the content of the request and send it. It wasn't pretty, but it worked and saved me an immense amount of time. The only downside was every time I had to log in to the site again, my authentication cookies got invalidated and I had to grab them again. But that I could live with.

They seem to have changed all their communication to https, because now instead of a request to

http://www.lingq.com/learn/ja/import/contents/?add

all I see in Fiddler is

"Tunnel to www.lingq.com/443"

Fiddler also gives me a warning that HTTPS decryption is disabled. When I enable it, and start capturing, Firefox gives me a certificate error when I try to access the site (or any other site that uses certificates, including Google):

> www.lingq.com uses an invalid security certificate.
>
> The certificate is not trusted because no issuer chain was provided.
>
> (Error code: sec_error_unknown_issuer)

My script is now completely useless, every request I send returns the login page. And because of Fiddler messing up the certificates, I can't further reverse engineer the site to mimic the requests correctly.

How can I make https decryption work in Fiddler? Alternatively, is there a way my script can properly authenticate itself on the site? I have tried the steps described here:
[How to make an authenticated web request in Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508565/how-to-make-an-authenticated-web-request-in-powershell)
It didn't work at all. My guess is some sort of federated authentication is in place, but frankly I'm completely out of my depth here.

Comment: Their [API docs](https://www.lingq.com/apidocs/) might also help.

Comment: They didn't. Their API doesn't seem have an import method. At least it's not in the documentation.

Comment: When decrypting HTTPS traffic, Fiddler works as a "man in the middle" proxy. i.e. You have to create a local SSL cert in Fiddler and configure your script to use proxy 127.0.0.1 (localhost).