# Copy all texts from browser and paste it to a txt file and save it. VBscript

Tags: vbscript

I have 30 different web pages, where I am trying to make a script to copy all the texts and paste it to 30 different txt files and save it - all in the background.

So far I successfully created one script for one web page, but I am having problems to create ONE .vbs file that will do it for all 30 pages.  I thought I can just copy/paste my code 30x to the bottom of the page and just modify the source/destination of the website and it would work. But it didnt.

```
With CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
  .Navigate "http://example.com"
  Do Until .ReadyState = 4
   Wscript.Sleep 100
   Loop

  .Document.execcommand "SelectAll"
  .Document.execCommand "copy"

End With

'paste
   Const ForAppending = 8   

  Dim sFSpec 
  sFSpec = ".\file1.txt" 

  Dim oIE 
  Dim sText 

  Set oIE = CreateObject( "InternetExplorer.Application" ) 
  oIE.Navigate( "about:blank" ) 
  sText   = oIE.document.parentwindow.clipboardData.GetData( "text" ) 
  CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )_ 
  .OpenTextFile( sFSpec, ForAppending, True )_ 
  .WriteLine sText 

   ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
  'Below, I just copy and paste it, but the code here doesn't work

  With CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
  .Navigate "http://example1.com" 

   Do Until .ReadyState = 4
   Wscript.Sleep 100
   Loop
  .Document.execcommand "SelectAll"
  .Document.execCommand "copy"

End With

'paste
  Const ForAppending = 8   
  Dim sFSpec1 

  sFSpec1 = ".\dev01-envVar.txt" 

  Dim oIE1 
  Dim sText1 

  Set oIE1 = CreateObject( "InternetExplorer.Application" ) 
  oIE1.Navigate( "about:blank" ) 
  sText1   = oIE1.document.parentwindow.clipboardData.GetData( "text" ) 
  CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )_ 
  .OpenTextFile( sFSpec, ForAppending, True )_ 
  .WriteLine sText
```

Or any other easier way than using vbscripting?

Also, IE always gives me this pop-up message - "Do you want to allow this webpage to access your clipboard?" How can I remove that pop up? [Remove this popup!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oci8N.jpg)

Comment: This statement - *"Or any other easier way than using vbscripting?"* makes the question too broad. See [ask] and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Why use the an instance of `InternetExplorer.Application` when a [`WinHttpRequest` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384106%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) will work just as well without the overheads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You marked your question with PowerShell tag so here it is:

```
"http://example.com", "http://gmail.com" | % {
    $ie = New-Object -ComObject internetexplorer.application
    $ie.Navigate($_)
    while ($ie.ReadyState -ne 4){
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
    }
    $ie.Document.execCommand("SelectAll") | Out-Null
    Out-File -InputObject $ie.Document.selection.createRange().text `
             -FilePath "D:\Temp\$($ie.Document.title).txt"
    $ie.Quit()
}
```

1. I changed this example slightly. It does not need clipboard access and does not pollute this area (you may have something valuable in clipboard), no need to change clipboard access permission, security is improved.
2. Files are named after page titles, you may change it.
3. Dont forget to dispose IE component. If it's not released, you end up having many of them as processes in background.

Comment: The the code they posted is quite clearly VBScript but just because they erronously tag it [tag:powershell] you'd thought you confuse the issue further.

Comment: If your going to use powershell why not suggest the [`System.Net.WebClient`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/509394/692942)?

Comment: Simply: because only text is needed. No tags, no style information, no scripts. It's not so easy to parse HTML.

Comment: That's an assumption due to the question not being clear and the approach the OP has taken, fact is none of you should have even attempted answering this question until it was improved.

Comment: Thank you @PawełDyl , this really helps. I was thinking using either Powershell or VBScript as I know both would work on what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Sinse you mentioned PowerShell tag:

**Edited to work in powershell v2.0**

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName system.windows.forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::Clear() # just to be sure

$sitesList = @(
    'http://example.com', 
    <#
        More sites here
    #>
    'http://www.example.com'
)

foreach ($site in $sitesList) {
    $ie = New-Object -ComObject "internetexplorer.application"
    $ie.Navigate($site)

    while ($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
    }

    $ie.Document.execCommand( "SelectAll" )
    $ie.Document.execCommand( "copy" )

    $filename = ($site -replace "^http://") + '.txt'


    [System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::GetText() | Out-File "D:\$filename" -Force
    [System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::Clear()

    $ie.Quit()
}
```

Comment: Hi, i copied the exact code but changed the Out-File location to a C:, and it doesnt work.... there is actually an error in line 3...                                                          " Missing expression after ','.
At line:3 char:29"  I removed the comma, and it can only copy to clipboard and it doesnt paste it to the textfile.

Comment: Just remove `,` in the third line :)

Comment: hi n01d, thanks for your super quick response.... however it can only copy to my clipboard, and not paste/save it to the textfile.

Comment: @EpicDeveloper I don't understand what do you mean... `Get-Clipboard | Out-File` writes your captured clipboard to file.

Comment: i understand that logic, but did that work for you?  because when I ran it, it didn't save the file to my Out-File location.

Comment: @EpicDeveloper Yes, it worked for me. But I just checked: `Get-Clipboard` does not work for powershell 2.0. I use 5.0. Let me check what works in PSv2.0, I'll edit the answer shortly.

Comment: There is no need to pollute clipboard, check my answer.

Comment: @PawełDyl Somehow i missed your answer O_o EpicDeveloper you should look into Pawel's answer - it is much more correct than mine.

Comment: The the code they posted is quite clearly VBScript but just because they erronously tag it [tag:powershell] you'd thought you confuse the issue further.

Comment: If your going to use powershell why not suggest the [`System.Net.WebClient`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/509394/692942)?

Comment: @Lankymart Same reason the topic starter decided not to use it in vbs.

Comment: Correction, they posted VBS code asking for help with the VBS then added - *"Or any other easier way than using vbscripting?"* which should send alarm bells ringing for any experienced [so] user. Plus that example is powershell I was pointing out using the `InternetExplorer.Application` is pointless we should to advising them to move to xhr.

Comment: @Lankymart What are you trying to say? If you have a good and correct answer - just post it. If it is better than mine - it will be accepted as correct. What do you want from all who answers to this question? And why have you removed powershell tag? As far as I can see author accepts PS answers as well.

Comment: What I'm saying is despite the question being unclear and ambiguous in nature you not only don't leave it well alone you post an answer. Not only that but it's a poor approach at best. We shouldn't be encouraging these types of questions and while people like yourself *attempt* to answer them people will keep posting them.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set AllWindows = objShell.Windows
For Each window in AllWindows
    msgbox window.locationname
    If window.locationname="Scripts" then window.quit
Next
```

This lists all open shell windows from Explorer and Internet Explorer.

Comment: Surprised you are encouraging use of `InternetExplorer.Application`, wouldn't have expected you to at least suggest a xhr approach.

Comment: That wouldn't answer his question of *in the browser*. His approach is flawed, but that wasn't his question.

Comment: The whole question is a mess, it's not clear and the approach is all wrong but still you leave an answer. Way to discourage bad questions @Noodles.