# Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed. Visual Studio and Chocolatey install problems

Tags: .net, powershell, visual-studio-express, chocolatey

**EDIT:**

I received similar error when doing an install of Visual Studio Express 2015, completely unrelated to my chocolatey endeavors. Unfortunately, I'm in unfamiliar territory with .NET technology and Windows, but I'll continue researching and will post a resolution should I find one. I think it is pretty safe to say this is no longer directly related to chocolatey install procedures.

```
[1548:154C][2016-07-23T20:14:14]i000: MUX:  Feed uri to register: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=558779&clcid=0x409
[1548:1574][2016-07-23T20:14:22]e000: MUX:  ERROR: TaskExceptionHolder_UnhandledException
[1548:1574][2016-07-23T20:14:22]e000: MUX:  Stack:    at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskExceptionHolder.Finalize()
[1548:1574][2016-07-23T20:14:22]e000: MUX:  Exception: Info: InnerException: Info:
[1548:1574][2016-07-23T20:14:22]e000: MUX:  ERROR: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.
[1548:1574][2016-07-23T20:14:22]e000: MUX:  Stack:    at System.Threading.Tasks.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.TelemetryManifestDownloader.<>c__DisplayClass1.<<Start>b__0>d__3.MoveNext()
```

**Original Post**:

None of the suggested install [commands](https://chocolatey.org/install) for Chocolatey seem to work. I should meet all the requirements: Windows version, .NET version, PowerShell version. I'm running the commands in admin windows. Execution policy appears to be `RemoteSigned`. I attempted changing that to `Unrestricted`, but that operation also fails.

[image: net]

[image: cmd]

[image: powershell]

The reply by `nslookup` gives me something. I was able to ping the address and able to get a bad HTTP request error out of the server using telnet.

```
PS C:\Users\griffic> nslookup chocolatey.org    
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    chocolatey.org
Addresses:  104.20.74.28
          104.20.73.28
```

Comment: There don't seem to be typos in your command, so the most likely explanation is that you simply cannot access chocolatey.org. Run `nslookup chocolatey.org` and `telnet chocolatey.org 443` to check if you can resolve the name and connect to port 443 (https) of the web server.

Comment: If the remote host can be reached, try inspecting the connection with [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to see if something goes wrong there. You may need to tell the `WebClient` object to [use a proxy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/571429/powershell-web-requests-and-proxies), though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing it has to do with proxy settings.

https://chocolatey.org/install#before-you-install and https://chocolatey.org/install#cmdpowershell-wproxy-server are where the install options talk about how to install Chocolatey behind a proxy.

The second directs you to https://chocolatey.org/docs/proxy-settings-for-chocolatey#installing-chocolatey-behind-a-proxy-server which has the following:

1. Copy the [install.ps1](https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1) file locally.
2. Open a PowerShell command line.
3. Set the following environment variables - `$env:chocolateyProxyLocation` (with proxyserver:proxyport), `$env:chocolateyProxyUser` (if it is a domain account, ensure you have the appropriate domain prefix for the account, e.g. `AD\UserName` or `UserName`), and `$env:chocolateyProxyPassword` with your password.
4. With that same shell open where the environment variables are set, run the downloaded script to install Chocolatey.

Comment: There was proxy server interference, although I didn't even know I had one. It is a company machine and they have one setup that automatically configures itself via some script for protection against malware and naughty websites. For chocolatey, all I had to do was copy the install script locally and run it. Didn't have to do anything else or set any environment variables. Chocolatey seemed fine once it got installed. For the visual studio install, I had to get IT to disable the proxy temporarily while it installed itself, and hopefully that'll be enough.

Comment: Most organizations that use Chocolatey do so with their own packages (using internally hosted or embedded software) and internal repositories. Something to consider...