# Schedule a URL request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, powershell, windows-7, curl

I need to make a request to an URL of my app, every 15 minutes(not hosting scheduled tasks), and I don't want anything sophisticated, just something simple, so I end up with this 2 solutions:

- Windows 7 scheduler + PowerShell Script
- Windows 7 scheduler + Curl request

Is there something else, similar, that I can do ?

Which of the 2 approaches is best ?

I really appreciate if someone can show me how to make a PowerShell Script doing an URL request or how to schedule on windows 7 a curl request.

Comment: This SO question has some pointers wrt making HTTP requests from PowerShell: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/340553/what-is-the-best-way-to-send-http-requests-from-windows-powershell. It's easy to create and use managed objects from PS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have [PowerShell 3](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27548) at hand, you could use the brand new [Invoke-WebRequest](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx) in your scheduled script. But having [something similar to curl](http://www.jim-melton.com/2012/03/06/use-powershell-instead-of-curl/) in PowerShell is relatively easy. From the article mentioned:

```
$document = New-Object -ComObject msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP
$document.open("POST", "https://www.somewhere.com", $false)
$document.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

$postline = " <Blah> "

$document.send($postline)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try a web based request scheduler like [iHook](https://ihook.us). If your app is not publicly accessible, you might also need a tunneling tool like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).